# how to make react webcam responsive

Tags: reactjs, webcam

```js
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Webcam from 'react-webcam';
import RadioButtonUncheckedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/RadioButtonUnchecked';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { setCameraImage } from './features/cameraSlice';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import './WebcamCapture.css';

const elem =
  document.compatMode === 'CSS1Compat'
    ? document.documentElement
    : document.body;
const videoConstraints = {
  width: elem.clientWidth,
  height: elem.clientHeight,
  facingMode: 'environment',
};

function WebcamCapture() {
  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const capture = useCallback(() => {
    const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
    dispatch(setCameraImage(imageSrc));
    history.push('/preview');
  }, [webcamRef]);

  return (
    <div className="webcamCapture">
      <Webcam
        audio={false}
        height={videoConstraints.height}
        ref={webcamRef}
        screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
        width={videoConstraints.width}
        videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
      />
      <RadioButtonUncheckedIcon
        className="webcamCapture__button"
        onClick={capture}
        fontSize="large"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default WebcamCapture;
```

```css
.webcamCapture {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.webcamCapture__button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
```

I want the video element to take after the screen's dimensions and take up 100% of the screen view at all times, including when browser is resized or when done on mobile but there seems to be a certain ratio restriction.

for mobile devices its not taking up the entire screen
please help me with the entire code so that it's responsive on all devices

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: the camera is not taking entire screen on mobile devices

Comment: Try: `height:100%;`,
       `width:100%;`

Comment: height:100% width:100% not working, it breaks on mobile devices and takes only half of screen's width how to make it fit on any device?

Answer (score 0):

To apply a custom style for mobile screens, you will have to detect mobile screens first using
[`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) then apply custom style.

I have added a solution below which I expect to work, detecting `640px` & `768px` max width devices and I have added `height:100%;`, `width:100%;`.

```css
.webcamCapture {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
}
 @media only screen and (max-device-width : 640px) {
     .webcamCapture {
         position:fixed;
         height:100%;
         width:100%;
    }
}
 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
     .webcamCapture {
         position:fixed;
         height:100%;
         width:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working on resizing browser but now on mobile devices